# Why does certain data imported from Word into Excel have yellow font, but not in Word?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-word, vba, fonts

Students fill out some tables in Word, and they must occasionally use a certain color font to get full credit.  I'm using VBA to import their data and the color of their font from their submitted documents.  Most of this comes out looking correct, but some comes out with yellow or orange font.

The most likely causes would be that the font was colored in those shades in the origin file or that there isn't any cleanup of formats being done before the macro is run again, but I've checked to make sure those aren't the case.  One other possibility I looked at was that the yellow color came from the yellow edit fields present when a Word file is protected.  I used some code to address that, but it had no effect.  Code is below for entire script:

```
Public Sub ImportWordData(folderPath As String)
    Dim wordApp As Word.Application
    Dim wordDoc As Word.Document
    Dim fso As Scripting.FileSystemObject
    Dim aFold As Scripting.Folder, aFile As Scripting.File
    Dim rngOutput As Range
    Dim wRange(0 To 20) As Word.Range
    Dim strOutput As String
    Dim lColor(0 To 20) As Long, lBColor(0 To 20) As Long
    Dim lTable(0 To 1) As Long
    Dim i As Long, x As Long, y As Long, z As Long
    
    wksRaw.Cells.Clear
    
    Set fso = New FileSystemObject
    Set aFold = fso.GetFolder(folderPath)
    Set wordApp = New Word.Application
    Set rngOutput = wksRaw.Range("B2")
    lTable(0) = wksStart.Range("G5").Value
    lTable(1) = wksStart.Range("G6").Value
    
    For Each aFile In aFold.Files
        
        If InStr(1, aFile.Name, "~") > 0 Or InStr(1, aFile.Name, "Importer") Then GoTo SkipLoop
              
        Set wordDoc = wordApp.Documents.Open(aFold.Path & Application.PathSeparator & aFile.Name)
        Call FixHighlights(wordApp, wordDoc)
        
        Set wRange(0) = wordDoc.Tables(lTable(0)).Rows(3).Cells(3).Range
        Set wRange(1) = wordDoc.Tables(lTable(0)).Rows(3).Cells(1).Range
        lColor(0) = wordDoc.Tables(lTable(0)).Rows(3).Cells(3).Range.Font.Color
        lColor(1) = wordDoc.Tables(lTable(0)).Rows(3).Cells(3).Range.Font.Color
        
        Debug.Print ("0: " & lColor(0) & " 1: " & lColor(1))
        x = 10
        
        For i = 3 To 10
            Set wRange(i - 1) = wordDoc.Tables(lTable(0)).Rows(i).Cells(2).Range
            lColor(i - 1) = wordDoc.Tables(lTable(0)).Rows(i).Cells(2).Range.Font.Color
        Next i
                
        For i = 2 To 6 Step 2
            Set wRange(x) = wordDoc.Tables(lTable(1)).Cell(19, i).Range
            lColor(x) = wordDoc.Tables(lTable(1)).Cell(19, i).Range.Font.Color
            x = x + 1
        Next i
    
        For i = 4 To 13
            If i = 8 Then i = 10
            Set wRange(x) = wordDoc.Tables(lTable(1)).Cell(i, 2).Range
            lColor(x) = wordDoc.Tables(lTable(1)).Cell(i, 2).Range.Font.Color
            x = x + 1
        Next i

        rngOutput.Cells(z + 1, 1).Value = wordDoc.Name
        
        For i = 0 To 20
            strOutput = WorksheetFunction.Trim(WorksheetFunction.Clean(wRange(i).Text))
            rngOutput.Cells(z + 1, i + 2).Value = strOutput
            rngOutput.Cells(z + 1, i + 2).Font.Color = lColor(i)
        Next i
        
        z = z + 1
        wordDoc.Close False
        
SkipLoop:
    Next aFile
    
    wksRaw.UsedRange.EntireColumn.ColumnWidth = 15
    
    On Error Resume Next
    wksRaw.Activate
    On Error GoTo 0

    wordApp.Quit False
    
    Set fso = Nothing
    Set wordDoc = Nothing
    Set wordApp = Nothing
    On Error GoTo 0
    
End Sub

Sub FixHighlights(wApp As Word.Application, wDoc As Word.Document)
    Dim oFF As FormField
    
    On Error Resume Next
    wDoc.FormFields.Shaded = False

    If wDoc.ProtectionType = wdAllowOnlyFormFields Then wDoc.Unprotect

    For Each oFF In wDoc.FormFields
        oFF.Range.HighlightColorIndex = wdNoHighlight
    Next

    wDoc.Protect wdAllowOnlyFormFields, NoReset:=True, Password:=""
    wApp.ActiveWindow.View.ShadeEditableRanges = False
    On Error GoTo 0
    
End Sub
```

The picture below is an example; I import the date from the table cell (in the lower half of pic) to Excel and it turns yellow.

[image: Yellow font from Word Table]